# Is there an application type in applescript?

Tags: applescript

Is there an application type in AppleScript?

I have this handler:

```
on doHandler(theApplication)

    set theApp to ("\"" & theApplication & "\"")
    tell application theApp
        set frontWindow to theApp's (window 1)
        etc.
    end tell

end doHandler
```

It is accessed as follows:

```
doHandler("TextEdit")
```

This produces the obvious error on theApp's (window 1).

So, what is the correct call?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work. The argument of `tell application` must be a literal string because the terminology is evaluated at **compile** time.

Apart from that the code doesn't work anyway because it expects that every application has an AppleScript dictionary containing a `window` property which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is eliminate the line `set theApp to...` and use the `its` keyword to set up the correct reference.

```
doHandler("TextEdit")

on doHandler(theApplication)
    tell application theApplication
        set frontWindow to its (window 1)
    end tell
end doHandler
```

In the main script, application references are established at compile time, so you can't have a variable app name, but handlers aren't evaluated until run time.